# Adding a frame style in a map with QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am new to QGIS and have a problem that some might be able to help me with.

Background: Windows 10 and all OS is up to date,
QGIS standalone version 2.18.13 (64 bit)

Learning tutorial http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html

When following this tutorial I can get up to step 21 but I can’t get the frame style to show up on the map?

---

My original post did not mention anything in regards to adding a grid and zebra border I can get that.
I don't know how to upload a screen caption but if you would have looked at the link I provided at step 21 you will see a pink rectangular box around the area of Tokyo which is a frame style.
This is what and can get.

Comment: did you mean that you can't figure to add a grid and zebra border to the main map ? please send a capture of your composer.

Comment: Step 21 is about grids, do you mean step 20 with the overview map which is shown as a transparent red rectangle?

Comment: Yes, step 20 showing as transparent red rectangangle.

Answer (score 5):

Follow step by step :

- Clic on the Map0 in item Panel
- Open Items Properties
- Clic on "Overview" arrow
- Create a new overview by clicking on +
- Clic on "Draw overview"
- Set the Map Frame list as Map1
- See the result

or look at this short video to do what you want

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want a frame, this look like this.
[image]